# Magento 2 some Product URLs show Category path

Tags: magento2

In my `magento 2.2.4` setup some products of some categories show the category path and some do not. i checked all settings but I dont see the difference.

In all store views (Default, etc.) I have setup "NO" for the below setting:

> Stores/Configuration/Catalog/Catalog/SearchEngineOptimisation/Use
>   Categories Path for Product URLs

I have ran the reindex several times but no results so far.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel and **Catalog => Category/Display Settings / Anchor** and check value . This setting change URL path product . (make clean cache and reindex)

Comment: Its the same in every category.

Comment: But I did that and no change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that URL rewrites cannot be recreated from nowhere.

SO please try the below extension and run the commands as mentioned there.

https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Comment: Is there a way to use this extension for only one URL? I fear to rewrite everything to avaoid other side effects.

Comment: @MichaelMüller you can edit the file (https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites/blob/master/Console/Command/RegenerateUrlRewrites.php) file and customize the `$categories` collection as per your requirement for a quick solution.