# Magento 2 Add category path to product page

Tags: magento2, url

How do I add category to breadcrumbs on products page so it says `Home -> Category -> Lenovo Thinkpad`

From the Admin panel I've set

**Use Categories Path for Product URLs** -> YES

But it only affected my url path.

Even thow I go directly to `Rootategory -> Components -> Lenovo Thinkpad` It stil says `Home -> Lenovo ThinkPad`

I've already checked this:

- [Magento 2 Get Full Category Path for product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272161/magento-2-get-full-category-path-for-product)
- [Magento 2 some Product URLs show Category path](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231929/magento-2-some-product-urls-show-category-path)
- [How to get category id by category path in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307700/how-to-get-category-id-by-category-path-in-magento-2)
- [Get product path from id with category path in url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52969/get-product-path-from-id-with-category-path-in-url)

[image]

Comment: which Magento version are you using?

Comment: Use this link hope this helps https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/magento-2-2-4-breadcrumbs-do-not-show-on-product-pages-when-default-navigation if need any help then comment

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of categories in the breadcrumbs is the default behavior in Magento > 2.3, however, it is tightly coupled with categories' 'Include in menu' option. If you choose not to include the category in the menu, then it will not show up in the breadcrumbs trail.

Also, if you directly access the product (and not navigate through categories to get to it), then it will show no category breadcrumbs trail (which is actually correct, you didn't use the categories, so there is no reason to have them in the breadcrumbs).

However, if you are not using Magento>2.3, then you will have to customly add the breadcrumbs. I found this module https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-full-path-category-product-breadcrumb which might help you with this. I didn't use it myself, but looks promissing.

Comment: Hi, could you help answer this. I checked the function `getFilteredCollection`, in: https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-full-path-category-product-breadcrumb/blob/7d64e1d13ae0d1551f2542995aa67747471085a7/Block/FullBreadcrumbs.php#L72

Comment: it loads all the category with condition `in`, my questions is does it slow when the categories are enormous?

Comment: hi there, well i didn't try this module myself as already mentioned, and i am not sure how this will impact your environment. but you could install blackfire.io and profile the performance of the pages so that you have a clearer view.

Comment: I haven't installed it either, I just want to know by looking at the code :D Blackfire is gold, thanks for your help!

Comment: you are most welcome! i hope you sort it out :) i just checked that class and honestly that IN condition should not be a problem, it's just searching through the list of category IDs that the current product is assigned to, shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

In this tutorial, I will show you how to display products of a specific category on a home page.

- Step 1: Please go to the Magento 2 admin panel > Product > Categories
- Step 2: Open the desired category then find the category ID like
  below image. Please take note of the category ID value, you will need
  to use in the next step.
- Step 3: In Magento 2 admin panel, please go
  to Content > Elements > Page > Choose desired Homepage
- Step 4.Open
  the content tab and insert the following HTML code

  {{block type=”catalog/product_list” category_id=”4″ template=”catalog/product/list.phtml”}}

If you want to display a specific number of column in product listing, you can use the following code:

```
{{block type=”catalog/product_list” column_count=”4″ category_id=”4″ template=”catalog/product/list.phtml”}}
```

- Step 5. Open Content > Elements > Blocks > Add New Blocks
- Step 6. Specify Block name as “catalog/product_list”
  allow the Block by choosing the YES/No for “Enable Block”

Comment: The image you reference in your answer is missing.

Comment: and this is relevant to the current question how?